# Issue with django smart_selects app

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-smart-selects

I am using django smart_selects app for a use case suitable to chained foreign keys. But somehow it just isn't working.

I have the app folder in my project directory, have included the necessary changes in my urls.py and ran a collectstatic as well. The chained foreign key however doesn't render anything on the admin page.

I can see "*Uncaught ReferenceError: chainedfk is not defined*" error in my console, but I checked and the files **chainedfk.js** and **chainedm2m.js** are present in my static folder as well.

P.S. I have overridden the default admin page for this model, could that be an issue? I've been stuck with this for hours, have seen a similar issue being faced by some other folks as well but there seems to be no valid answer that would work for me here. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure, you did a collectstatic if you not in debug mode

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```